# Advice for adding a verification badge after username

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, user-interface

What would be the best way to display a verification badge after someones username on a website with the use of jQuery, JavaScript, PHP, HTML, CSS. I can echo the badge with an `isset($user[verification])` but I think code and server technically this is not the best idea since the code needs to be after each username. What would be the best approach on this?

Examples:

[image: Instagram example]
[image: Twitter example]

Comment: Create a function that checks the user and verification status, then returns the name, and badge, if applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very minimum the application will be determining whether or not a user is verified, meaning that there will be some server side code involved.  Whether you generate the html from the php, or trigger some javascript based on a session variable doesn't really matter.

Second, no matter what solution you go with when a user sends you some information if there is any conditional logic that should restrict them based on whether or not they are verified you will need to re-validate this on the server side again anyway when they submit anything.

The look and positioning of the icon would be most efficiently accomplished using css because that is what styles are for, but passing a theoretical "verified" class down to a span could be done any number of ways.